# Component on JPanel not showing in original size

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, components

I made a basic game on a JFrame and I'm currently trying to add a scoreboard on top my frame by using two separate JPanels. I tried to do it with WindowBuilder but the problem is that my GameFrame class component isn't shown fully in the game frame. It looks like this:

[image]

The code is as follows:

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game");
    frame.setSize(500, 700);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(0, 100, 500, 600);
    panel.add(new GameFrame());
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: For better help sooner post a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `JPanel` uses `FlowLayout` by default which respects preferred sizes. As its unlikely that this is currently overridden for your `GameFrame` component class, you need to use a layout manager which uses the maximum area available

```
panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much. Guess I need to read more about layouts.

Answer (score 0):

I think setting the layout to null is this issue. Set a proper Layout as shown below

```
frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried one of these: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html ?
If so, what's not working?

A BorderLayout could be useful if you want the scoreboard along the top, by using panel.add(new ScoreBoard(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START) for example.